# MikTeX 2.9 / XeLaTeX - how to display soft hyphen character (0x00ad)

Tags: xetex

I'd like to ask for the advice how to display character 0x00ad.

I need to display characters from a `.ttf` font and one of required characters - `0x00ad` - is processed as a control command. It selects the hyphenation point in the word instead of displaying it.

How to force displaying this character?

- place it directly into source code doesn't work
- `\symbol{"00ad}` doesn't work
- `\char"00ad` doesn't work
- `^^^^00ad` doesn't work

It shall be obviously somehow placed into text after preprocessing phase, otherwise it hyphenates the word instead of displaying character specified by font.

Maybe there is some other solution, eg. somehow patch the generated PDF?
Every idea is welcome :-)

I use distribution MikTeX (recently updated version), XeLaTeX compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it active and give it a definition. But I have no idea which look you want so I used XXX here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\catcode`\^^^^00ad=13 \def^^^^00ad{XXX}^^^^00ad}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

It is not easy to show the "real glyph". harfbuzz -- the library used by xetex for the font shaping -- replaces the char at a quite low level. But the following worked for me for the default font latin modern:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\XeTeXglyph 542

\end{document}
```

It shows a hyphen and copies to babelpad as 00AD.

The number "542" is the glyph slot and it is font dependant. I found the number by looking in `lmroman10-regular.lua` for the index number of position 173 (=AD):

```
 [173]={
   ["boundingbox"]=3,
   ["index"]=542,
   ["unicode"]=173,
   ["width"]=333,
  },
```

An alternative is to use lualatex. It doesn't replace the soft hyphen:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
x^^^^00adx 

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

while the xetex output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need the completely opposite. Your example shows how to replace the 00ad character with the XXX sequence, but what I need is to display character 00ad itself, because the TTF font contains some drawing for this char. I've shortly tested replacement of other character with 00ad based of your example, but the result is the same: character 00ad is always "gobbled", because it's treated like control char (soft hyphenation) and nothing is displayed. I've also tried to set 00ad category 11 (letter) instead of 13 (active character), but without success.

Comment: How do  you know that the ttf itself contains a visible glyph? Is the font available?

Comment: It's visible in MS Word when you click Insert Symbol - there is a map of available characters in font including unicode hex. Also copy&paste from.to other editors works fine. Font is available for example here: https://www.ceskefonty.cz/ceske-fonty/fr-kms-01cs (https://www.ceskefonty.cz/ceske-fonty-zdarma-ke-stazeni/200/ttf_fr_kms_01cs.zip). Character 00ad contains widely-used variant of letter "s". Workaround could be to alter TTF using FontForge, but I'd prefer to find a TeX solution :-)

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Difficult case :-) XeTeXglyph works fine for fonts delivered with the distribution, but not for external .ttf :-) When I displayed all glyphs from the fr-kms-01cs.ttf, exactly the 00ad was missing :-) Are there some parameters of package fontspec or \setmainfont which imports all glyphs from the ttf? If not, I guess the easiest solution is to alter .ttf and relocate 00ad to other position, or generate "gothic" page in different editor and insert non-TeX pdf into my document using \includegraphics :-)

Comment: `\XeTeXglyph 93 ` worked for me with your font.

Comment: Ooops, my mistake. I've prepared list of glyphs manually and accidentally omitted all indexes ending xx3... I confirm your solution works perfectly.